# PHP Regex No Backslash

Tags: php, regex, escaping, backslash

So I hadn't done any regexps for a while, so I thought I'd brush up on my memory. I'm trying to convert a string like `a*b*c` into `a<b>b</b>c`. I've already gotten that working, but now I want to keep a string like `a\*b\*c` from turning into `a\<b>b\</b>c`, but rather, into `a*b*c`. Here's the code I'm using now:

```
     $string = preg_replace("/\*([\s\S]*?)\*/", "<b>$1</b>", $input);
```

I've tried putting this `\\\\{0}` in before the asterisks, and that didn't work. Neither did `[^\\\\]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try negative lookbehind:

```
"/(?<!\\\\)\*([\s\S]*?)(?<!\\\\)\*/"
```

This only matches a `*` if it's not preceded by a `\`.

This is brittle, though; it would also fail if the string is `escaped backslash \\*bold* text`.

Comment: I get an error when trying that: `Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Compilation failed: missing ) at offset 26`

Comment: When I use four backslashes, instead of two, it works exactly like I need it to! Thanks!

Comment: Ah yes, right. You do need four backslashes - I have corrected my answer.